# Swagger annotation to handle org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.multipart.Attachment

Tags: rest, jax-rs, cxf, swagger, swagger-2.0

I am a process of developing a REST API which accepts file and performs some business specific operation, Since we are using apache cxf 3.1.0 For JAXRS implantation , The endpoint automatically takes Attachment instead of Inputstream

```
public Response sampleAPI(
            @ApiParam(value = "File to be uploaded.", required = true) 
            @Multipart(value = "file", required = true) Attachment file){
       // Some Logic 
     }
```

Now as we need to publish this API using swagger output it displays is of complex type attachment.

[image]

So any consumer who needs to send the file gets an impression he needed to use CXF API to send his file to the endpoint which is a problem for us.

Is there any way in either swagger annotation or we can change the attachment as an argument in our API to standard say inputstream so that consumer of the API may not get confused.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `@ApiImplicitParam` annotation here. 
So for the code snippet mentioned in your question, the following should work

```
  @ApiImplicitParams({
      @ApiImplicitParam(name = "file", value = "File to be uploaded.", required = true, dataType = "file", paramType = "form")
  })
  public Response sampleAPI(
      @ApiParam(hidden = true) @Multipart(value = "file", required = true) Attachment file){
    // Some Logic 
  }
```

Note that I have marked the `Attachment` method argument as `hidden` so that swagger does not display it, as it is showing currently for you.